# Сделать реагирование на кнопку Java

Tags: java

Как сделать так, чтобы пока не нажата клавиша Enter, дальше код не работал. Хочу, так сказать, консольный интерфейс на Java сделать

Comment: Считывать строки можно при помощи метода [`Scanner::nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)

Comment: Лучше книгу шилда полное руководство по java почитайте,  там много примеров консольных программ

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно отследить в графическом, то можно воспользоваться таким вариантом.

```
public void onKeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        System.out.println("Вы нажали Enter");
    }
}
```

Если речь идет о консольном варианте, то можно воспользоваться, к примеру, такой конструкцией:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            int buttonKeyCode;
            char buttonCharacter;

            while ((buttonKeyCode = System.in.read()) != -1) {
                buttonCharacter = (char) buttonKeyCode;

                if('\n' == buttonCharacter) {
                    System.out.println("Вы нажали Enter");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот ещё один вариант со StringBuilder:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        int charValue;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

        try {

            while ((charValue = reader.read()) = -1) {
                builder.append((char)charValue);

                if(10 == charValue) {
                    System.out.println(builder.toString());
                    builder.setLength(0);
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Вот вариант через InputStreamReader (со StringBuilder):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            int buttonKeyCode;
            char buttonCharacter;

            while ((buttonKeyCode = System.in.read()) != -1) {
                buttonCharacter = (char) buttonKeyCode;

                if('\n' == buttonCharacter) {
                    System.out.println("Вы нажали кнопку Enter");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Обновил код для обработки клавиш в консоли, т.к. предыдущий вариант был не совсем корректный. Добавил на всякий случай несколько вариантов кода для понимания.

**UPDATE #2**: С обработкой нажатий стрелок, увы, не подскажу, т.к. я изучал Java для разработки под Android.

Comment: Я хотел бы использование не только символов, а ещё и других клавиш, таких как стрелки